# Find the largest price from a separate file using classes and pointers

Tags: c++, class, pointers, switch-statement, swap

**This is for Homework**

So this is a function that works fine. I have to find the most expensive car from a file and have it print to the terminal. I'll post my function and clarify what I have below.

---

Here is how the file is formatted

Hertz 93619

2014 Toyota Tacoma 115.12 1

2012 Honda CRV 85.10 0

2015 Ford Fusion 90.89 0

2013 GMC Yukon 110.43 0

2009 Dodge Neon 45.25 1

---

Alamo 89502

2011 Toyota Rav4 65.02 1

2012 Mazda CX5 120.75 1

2016 Subaru Outback 71.27 0

2015 Ford F150 112.83 1

2010 Toyota Corolla 50.36 1

---

Budget 93035

2008 Ford Fiesta 42.48 0

2009 Dodge Charger 55.36 1

2012 Chevy Volt 89.03 0

2007 Subaru Legacy 59.19 0

2010 Nissan Maxima 51.68 1

---

```
void mostExpense(Agency *agencyptr)
{
float largest = 0.0f;
int agencyPosition = 0;
int carPosition = 0;

Car *carptr = agencyptr -> inventory;

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        if ((carptr -> getPrice()) > largest)
        {
            largest = carptr -> getPrice();
            agencyPosition = i + 1;
            carPosition = j + 1;
        }
        carptr++;
    }
    agencyptr++;
    carptr = agencyptr -> inventory;
}

switch (agencyPosition)
{
    case 1:
        agencyptr--; agencyptr--; agencyptr--;
        carptr = agencyptr -> inventory;
        switch (carPosition)
        {
            case 1:
                carptr -> print();
                break;
            case 2:
                carptr++;
                carptr -> print();
                break;
            case 3:
                carptr++; carptr++;
                carptr -> print();
                break;
            case 4:
                carptr++; carptr++; carptr++;
                carptr -> print();
                break;
            case 5:
                carptr++; carptr++; carptr++; carptr++;
                carptr -> print();
                break;
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        agencyptr--; agencyptr--;
        carptr = agencyptr -> inventory;
        switch (carPosition)
        {
            case 1:
                carptr -> print();
                break;
            case 2:
                carptr++;
                carptr -> print();
                break;
            case 3:
                carptr++; carptr++;
                carptr -> print();
                break;
            case 4:
                carptr++; carptr++; carptr++;
                carptr -> print();
                break;
            case 5:
                carptr++; carptr++; carptr++; carptr++;
                carptr -> print();
                break;
        }
        break;
    case 3:
        agencyptr--;
        carptr = agencyptr -> inventory;
        switch (carPosition)
        {
            case 1:
                carptr -> print();
                break;
            case 2:
                carptr++;
                carptr -> print();
                break;
            case 3:
                carptr++; carptr++;
                carptr -> print();
                break;
            case 4:
                carptr++; carptr++; carptr++;
                carptr -> print();
                break;
            case 5:
                carptr++; carptr++; carptr++; carptr++;
                carptr -> print();
                break;
        }
        break;
}
}
```

---

So what I have for my project is that we are given 3 different companies that give out car rentals. Each company has 5 cars. What I have right now works but it's redundant and it is nearly 200 lines of code. The main issue I have is with my switch statements. I have 3 different cases(Each for the 3 car rental places) and I start with the last car rental place first. Then I go through every single car and find the price. I do this over an iteration of 3 times and my if function tests the car prices against each other and then eventually prints out the most expensive car. What I want to do is change my procedure using the switch statements. How would I make it so this function is much shorter but still gives out the same output. I've tried quite a few things, but this is the only one that actually works, and I'd like to have something that's much shorter so when I do similar projects in the future I don't have nearly 1000 lines of code in one file to do something that should be fairly simple.

Any help would be appreciated!

Also if any clarification is needed please let me know in the comments.

The price is after the make and model

The 0's and 1's are true/false (If the car is available or not)

Comment: Are we supposed to guess that the price of the car is listed after the make and model in your input file?

Comment: @JustinRandall sorry I see that its kind of confusing the way I posted it, I'' fix it right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you can reduce the agencyPosition switch case to a single subtraction. First ensure that agencyPosition is 1 or 2 or 3. And then subtract 4 - agencyPosition from agencyPtr.

Note that: 4-1 = 3, 4-2 = 2, 4-3 = 1.

```c
if (agencyPosition >= 1 and agencyPosition <= 3) {
    agencyPtr -= 4 - agencyPosition;
    carptr = agencyptr -> inventory;
    switch (carPosition)
    // Everything else remains the same.
}
```

Comment: would that get rid of the 3 cases I have for agencies

Comment: Yes, you can verify this by performing 4 - agencyPosition with the cases 1, 2, or 3.

Comment: Im sorry, can you clarify on what you mean by preforming 4

Comment: So in case 1 of agencyPosition, you do `agencyptr--; agencyptr--; agencyptr--;`
Note that this is equivalent to doing `agencyPosition -= 3`, which reduces agencyPosition by 3. Next you have to notice that in `case 2` you reduce agencyPosition by 2 and in `case 3` you reduce it by 1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164871/discussion-between-chrishg-and-amourk).